# C# Get URL of page that submitted a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a master page that contains a SmallSearchInputBox (SharePoint control for searching). This masterpage is used by every page on my SharePoint site. There's a single results page (results.aspx), and I want to know on which page the SmallSearchInputBox was used and submitted when viewing the results on results.aspx.

I tried the usual suspects (`Request.UrlReferrer`,`Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]`, etc) but these don't appear to work when forms are involved.

Is there another way I can get the URL of the previous page when viewing my results page?

I suspect this is a standard C# question rather than a SharePoint one, though I have asked the same question from a SharePoint specific approach here: [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24993/from-search-results-page-how-to-determin-url-of-previous-page-where-smallsearch)

Comment: Using a form should have no impact on Request.UrlReferrer or Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] as these come from the headers sent by your browser. My test of a form that posts to another ASPX page has the Request.UrlReferrer filled in.

Comment: Interesting. Both Request.UrlReferrer and Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] (which I believe are essentially the same anyway) return null when i try this. Perhaps it's to do with master pages and/or SharePoint itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to results.aspx there's a queystring. In that querstring there is a parameter `u`, which contains the relative URL of the site containing the page with the SmallSearchInputBox.

Thanks to Splash-X and Moo-Juice for their help :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the url of whatever page you're on in the form that is submitting the expression?

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="POST" method="mypage.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" id="referer" name="referer" value="somepage.aspx?somevar=20" />
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. The SmallSearchInputBox is an ootb SharePoint control, and not one I can customize. Ideally the solution would be someone that can be done on results.aspx only that can determine the previous page URL.

Comment: You can ALWAYS create a new user control that inherits from the OOTB SmallSearchInputBox and inject your own custom field called "referrer" that does exactly what Moo-Juice has outlined. I think the bigger question would be why is the Request.UrlReferrer blank.

Comment: @Splash-X, I agree, the deeper question is why there is no referral.  Perhaps an issue with SharePoint?

Comment: I agree on both counts. I'm currently looking at extending the SmallSearchInputBox control, or replacing it, but yeah.. the more important (I think) questons is why is referrer null (if I can resolve that, then I can stick with the ootb control - the preferred option.

Comment: @QMKevin Keep in mind that both variables are the same. They are populated from headers sent from the browser. Go get Fiddler, install it and run some tests. See if the varaible is being pass over to the server or not. I could help if the pages were public but I assume it isn't?

Comment: @QMKevin, can I ask what browse you are using to test?  Also, do you navigate directly to the form in question to test?  Have you seen what happens if you go to say, page 1, then go to the page with the form and *then* submit?  Is `UrlReferrer` still `null`, then?

Comment: @Splash-X No, the pages are currently in development and not public, but I'll check Fiddler to see what's what.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I'm using IE mostly, but have them all (and various versions). The SmallSearchInputBox control is in my master page, so I basically go to any page, enter a search term and hit enter. Clearly the referrer won't be available if I go directly to the results, but then the results would be empty to if you don't enter a search term somewhere ;)

Comment: @QMKevin, agreed :)  I was wondering if it would still be `null` if you went to any page, *then* to a page with a search term and hit submit.

Comment: I Just tried that, and yes, it's still `null`. That said.. I'm an idiot! When you get to `results.aspx` there's a queystring. Had I looked at the whole querystring, I'd have seen the parameter `u`, which contains the relative URL of the site containing the page with the SmallSearchInputBox. Fiddler pointed that out to me, in no uncertain terms, and this is all I need to know whether to hide the refinements box or not. Thank you both for your patience and help :)

Comment: @QMKevin, no problem.  You should put that as an answer and mark it as the accepted one.  This helps others easily find the solution when they have a similar problem.  Happy coding!